# MySQL Query faster alternative to DISTINCT and REGEXP

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns combined locations e.x `Arizona, California` from the locations table only where each individual location `Arizona | Yes` and `California | Yes` has been selected by the user in the users table. It works, but it’s really slow. Is there a faster way to write this?

```
SELECT *
FROM locations
WHERE combined_locations NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT combined_locations
    FROM locations
    JOIN users ON locations.combined_locations REGEXP users.user_locations
    WHERE users.user_selection = 'No'
    AND users.user_id = 1
)
AND combined_locations IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT combined_locations
    FROM locations
    JOIN users ON locations.combined_locations REGEXP users.user_locations
    WHERE users.user_selection = 'Yes'
    AND users.user_id = 1
);
```

I’ve read that REGEXP is slow, so I’ve tried `LIKE CONCAT('%', users.user_locations, '%')` but it was only marginally faster.

I have also tried various indexing combinations but they didn’t seem to get much improvement.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/-Hb1rqTm

I’m still learning how to write good questions, so hopefully this is better than my first post.

Comment: MySQL optimises `IN` and `NOT IN` reasonably well, but you might find better peformance just with a simple join.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Your query does not check that ALL `combined_locations` places are present in `user_locations`. Comment the row (1, 'Arizona', 'Yes') and ensure..

Comment: @Akina. Thanks, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You might get faster performance using `FIND_IN_SET` and a couple of joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT locations.*
FROM locations
INNER JOIN users users_include ON
  users_include.user_id = 1      
  AND FIND_IN_SET(users_include.user_locations, locations.combined_locations) > 0
  AND users_include.user_selection = 'Yes'
LEFT JOIN users users_exclude ON
  users_exclude.user_id = 1
  AND FIND_IN_SET(users_exclude.user_locations, locations.combined_locations) > 0
  AND users_exclude.user_selection = 'No'
WHERE users_exclude.user_id IS NULL
```

Note that the logic implemented here is "*at least one* location with user_selection = 'Yes' and no location with user_selection = 'No'" - I think this is the same as the logic implemented by your query.

If the logic instead should be "*all* locations with user_selection = 'Yes' and no location with user_selection = 'No'", that can be accomplished with a `GROUP BY` clause and a `HAVING` clause (with a count):

```
SELECT locations.*
FROM locations
INNER JOIN users users_include ON
  users_include.user_id = 1
  AND FIND_IN_SET(users_include.user_locations, locations.combined_locations) > 0
  AND users_include.user_selection = 'Yes'
LEFT JOIN users users_exclude ON
  users_exclude.user_id = 1
  AND FIND_IN_SET(users_exclude.user_locations, locations.combined_locations) > 0
  AND users_exclude.user_selection = 'No'
WHERE users_exclude.user_id IS NULL
GROUP BY locations.id, locations.column1, locations.column2, locations.combined_locations
HAVING (1 + CHAR_LENGTH(combined_locations) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(combined_locations, ',', ''))) = COUNT(users_include.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT locations.id, locations.combined_locations
FROM users
JOIN locations ON FIND_IN_SET(users.user_locations, locations.combined_locations)
WHERE users.user_id = 1
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING SUM(users.user_selection = 'No') = 0
   AND SUM(users.user_selection = 'Yes') = 1 + LENGTH(locations.combined_locations) - LENGTH(REPLACE(locations.combined_locations, ',', ''))
```

Comment: That's neater than mine - nice

Comment: But still can't user indexes locations table due to the OP's user of comma delimited lists.

Comment: Also, if the user has selected three items, but the location consists of two items, this can still return the location.

Comment: @MatBailie *if the user has selected three items, but the location consists of two items, this can still return the location* If OP needs in ALL selected items are present in the locations list then we'd use CROSS JOIN, add user_selection = 'Yes' to WHERE and move FIND_IN_SET to HAVING. Anycase one join + GROUP BY + counting conditional SUMs can solve. *still can't user indexes locations table* Cannot be healed without normalizing.

Comment: ***Cannot be healed without normalizing*** : Being that performance is the OP's primary concern here, normalization will yield the largest benefits.

Comment: @Akina. Can you show the query with the cross join if two or more locations are in the combined_location column? Would it work if there were 3,4,5 or more?

Comment: @MatBailie. Normalization?

Comment: @Lexi_Collins See my link in the comments to your original post.

Comment: @MatBailie. Thanks. That’s going to take a deep dive and is currently way over my head.

Comment: In short; ***do not*** store multiple values a comma separated lists.  Instead, each value should be a separate row.  A rough and ready example might be; https://dbfiddle.uk/HDSzPlpR

Comment: @MatBailie. Wow, thanks. I might be able to rebuild over time. I think for now if Akina has an example with cross join so it can work if there are more combined locations that should suffice.

Comment: Without normalization, rows with ``user_locations`` like ``Georgia`` and ``Georgia, United States``  will cause you a lot of problems.

Comment: @ValNik. I’m debating rebuilding the table / data. For future proofing I could have up to 17 locations, I’m assuming that means 17 columns plus the combined column? Will a design like this be easier and faster?

Comment: It will be cumbersome and inconvenient. As for performance, we can only say if we look at typical queries. See this(https://dbfiddle.uk/wAe8mYne) example.